# Jupyter Notebook ImportError: cannot import name 'example_var'

Tags: python, import, jupyter-notebook, data-science

When I change/add a variable to my `config.py` file and then try to import it to my Jupyter Notebook I get:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'example_var' from 'config'`

> config.py:

```
example_var = 'example'
```

> jp_notebook.ipynb:

```
from config import example_var

print(example_var)
```

But after I restart the Jupyter Kernel it works fine until I modify the `config.py` file again. I read somewhere that it's because jupyter already cached that import. Is there any other way to delete that cache so I don't have to restart the kernel every time I make a change in the `config.py` file. Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [autoreload](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/extensions/autoreload.html) to reload modules every new cell execution.

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
from config import example_var

print(example_var)
```

Answer (score 0):

Also works in Notebooks when you work in a `.py` file and you always need a reloaded version in the notebook.

[image]